# Horizontal scrollbar on tabPage

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, tabpage

**Working in Design mode on Visual Studio 2010...**

I am trying to get an horizontal scrollbar on a tabPage. From what I understood by reading here and there, setting the `AutoScroll` property of the tabPage to `True` should be enough to get scrollbars.

When I place a element on my tabPage that exceeds the bottom limit of the tabPage, I get an vertical scrollbar. But when I make an element exceed the right limit of the tabPage, no horizontal scrollbar appears.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the problem: the control I was placing on my tabPage had the `Anchor` property set to **Top, Left, Right**. It cannot work if there is **Right**.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely doing something wrong there. I have just create a tabcontrol, set "AutoScroll" to true, selected the tab page element and added a new panel control (for testing). When I resize the control both the vertical and horizontal scroll bars are shown.

Are you sure you do not have any nested control elements? Perhaps the control that you think is outside the tab area is within a control than does not exceed the tab page bounds? In which case the scroll would not show

Comment: Weird, seems like a bug. I also tested on another tabPage and it works fine. But on the one I am working with, only the vertical scrollbar appears. The control is not within another one, I don't have anything nested...

Comment: @ Leito, Well, considering it is the TabPage control I would not be surprised. I have not had the best of experiences using this control in the past

Comment: +1 - I also did a quick test and all works fine for me.  But, if I drop a too big control in a not-too-big control, I get no scroll bars.  `AutoScroll = true` must be set on the parent of the too big control.

Comment: @gilly3 I found my problem, see my answer. Thanks to you two for testing though!

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal scrollbar problem can be caused Also if Dock = Fill . 
It should be Dock = None with Anchor= Right or Anchor= Left but not both.